# Is there a word for children under 10 years old?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the counterpart of the term "teenager" for those who are younger than 10 years old. A **single** word that means something like "elementary school student" is helpful as well.

Comment: Younger than ten?   - a newborn baby? an infant? a tiny tot?  a toddler?  a child?  a kid?

Comment: @Centaurus I am looking for a formal term for students in elementary schools. I mean "teenager" is formal to middle/high school students and I want an analogous term for younger people.

Comment: There's "preteen", but that's generally taken to include those up through age 12, and tends to exclude kids younger than 8 or 10.

Comment: (Note that "teenager" means those between 13 and 19, inclusive.)

Comment: [teenage](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/teenage): *between 13 and 19 years old.*

Comment: In the US,  "K-5"?

Comment: In Britain they would mostly be referred to as *a primary-school child* or *child of primary-school age*. Primary school = ages 4 to 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find a single word--if there were one, education departments would use it. Across New York State Education Department documents, students in elementary school (usually kindergarten through 5th or 6th grade, depending on the district) are referred to as "elementary students."

[NY State Department of Education](http://search.its.ny.gov/search?q=%22elementary%20student%22&site=nysed_p12_collection&btnG=Search&client=nysed_part100_frontend&proxystylesheet=nysed_part100_frontend&output=xml_no_dtd&sort=date%3AD%3AL%3Ad1&wc=200&wc_mc=1&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&ud=1&exclude_apps=1)

Answer (score 1):

The AAP calls them **gradeschoolers**.

Personally, I call them “school-aged children.”

> Gradeschooler: 5-12 yrs.

https://www.healthychildren.org/English/ages-stages/Pages/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

10-12 is a *tween*: short form of *tweenager* (ˈtwēnˌājər)

noun informal

a preteen or a young teenager.
"the hot Nickelodeon show for tweenagers" -- [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define+tweenager)

So perhaps you could coin *pretween*, meaning younger than a *tween*.

Answer (score -1):

a few words come to mind, you could use...

Child  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/child

"A human being below the age of puberty or below the legal age of majority."

You could also use minor
http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/minor

a person under the age of full legal responsibility.
"the court would take account of the minor's wishes"

Comment: But the "age of full legal responsibility" is generally 18, so "minor" doesn't work.

Comment: I think you're right,

Comment: Minor is tied with child, but it's only a synonym